# Submit form with date-steps without reloading page

Tags: php, html

I have a sign-up page where I use data-steps for each step. This is working fine. However, for my own needs, I need to figure out how I am able to send the php request without refreshing the page.

To prevent refreshing in the form I have to use

```
<button type="button" name="register">
```

But how am I able to send the request to php when the button type = button. I have seen posts where people say I need to use jquery. I get that. But, how? Can anyone explain me that over here?

I want to use Jquery and this, but how do I get my form input in that data and especially how do I receive those in php?

```
    $('#submit').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'register.inc.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            email: 'HOW DO I GET FORM INPUT HERE?',
            username: 'HOW DO I GET FORM INPUT HERE?'
        },
        success: function(msg) {
            alert('Register succesful!');
        }               
    });
});
```

Thanks for the effort, already.

EDIT:
I got this now:

```
    <script>
  $(function () {
    $('button').bind('click', function (event) {

    event.preventDefault();

      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '../includes/register.inc.php',
        data: $('form').serialize(),
        success: function () {
          alert('yoope');
        }
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

Above scripts work. However, it is giving me the alert always and does not use the errors I give in the php script anymore. How to fix?

Comment: you are looking for XMLHttpRequest, or Fetch.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Comment: yes, ajax is XmlHTTPRequest ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always use **return false** to stop the form from loading.

If you are using JQuery, something like this (submit the form and stop loading)

```
$('#myForm').submit(function () {
 return false;
});
```

or you could call another function to do the data handling from the form then stop the load

```
<form name="myForm" onsubmit="myFunction()">
....
....
</form>

<script>
function myFunction()
{
  //handle data

  //stop the form
  return false;
}
</script>
```